# where is the route.php file in laravel v5.3.10?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I download latest laravel project **v5.3.10** but i cannot find route file and some others.
[image][image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`routes.php` is no longer exists in Laravel 5.3 but there is a new routes directory on your root project folder, it contains two files `web.php` and `api.php` .

Those two files provide more explicit guidance in how to split the routes for your web interface and your API. The routes in the api route file are automatically assigned the api prefix by the RouteServiceProvider.

for further informations check [Laravel 5.3 release notes](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/releases).

Answer (score 2):

You have the `routes` directory in the root of your application.

Answer (score 2):

The route file in a directory. Please check this,

[image: route in laravel5.3]

Answer (score 2):

app/routes/web.php
you can write your all route files here

The web.php file contains routes that the RouteServiceProvider places in the web middleware group, which provides session state, CSRF protection, and cookie encryption. If your application does not offer a stateless, RESTful API, all of your routes will most likely be defined in the web.php file.

Read more about laravel 5.3 structure [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/structure#the-routes-directory)

Answer (score 1):

In the new laravel 5.3 there is no file named as `routes.php` in `App/HTTP/`
In the new laravel you can find a new folder as `routes`
Inside it there is `web.php` It is the new routes.php file
You can edit `web.php`  file just as you edit laravel 4 or older

[image]